# find column number in a line using emacs

Tags: emacs, gedit

I am working on a file which has very long line.
I am getting the error as  :

```
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 91115 (char 91115)
```

I want to find that but gedit stucks because of huge line.
using emacs I can view the line number.
but. how can I view the column number of line from emacs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`M-x column-number-mode`

Bla bla bla, because the answer is not long enough for the system ;-).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to that column then you can move to the start of the line and then hit `C-u 91115 C-f` which fordwards point by 91115 chars.